# Rails change column to mediumtext

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration

I need to change a column from type TEXT to MEDIUMTEXT. As per this discussion: [How to store long text to MySql DB using Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830522/how-to-store-long-text-to-mysql-db-using-rails), I will need to specify a limit on size as half of the allowable range for that particular TEXT type in MySQL. However, what I am experiencing is that even by halving, I'm still getting the type that's one level above what I need. Does anyone have a better doc where this was documented or know why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Is having a field that's "too big" really going to be the end of the world? The overhead is a couple of bytes per row at the absolute maximum.

Comment: It's not. I just would like to understand further about how Rails handle this issue though.

Comment: If you could be more specific about what you want and what you're getting and how you got it, it would be easier to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

See this answer: '[Rails 3 Migration with longtext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443477/rails-3-migration-with-longtext)'

The reason why the limit values you're inputting are being ignored is due to how MySQL works. It has four text types, each with their own size limit:

- TINYTEXT - 256 bytes
- TEXT - 65,535 bytes
- MEDIUMTEXT - 16,777,215 bytes
- LONGTEXT - 4,294,967,295 bytes

A text column needs to be one of those four types. You can't specify a custom length for these types in MySQL.

So if you set a limit on a :text type column, Rails will automatically pick the smallest of those types that can accommodate that value, silently rounding up the limiting value you inputted to one of those four limits above.

Example:

```
t.text :example_text_field, limit: 20
```

will produce a TINYTEXT field with a limit of 256 bytes, whereas

```
t.text :example_text_field, limit: 16.megabytes - 1
```

will produce a MEDIUMTEXT field with a limit of 16,777,215 bytes.

#### Update

For the shake of the question: *"I need to change a column"*

```
change_column :example_table, :example_text_field, :text, limit: 16.megabytes - 1
```

Comment: one can also use `limit: 16.megabytes- 1`

Comment: @nurettin I edited the question because in deed for the _mediumtext_ I needed to put `limit: 16.megabytes - 1`

Comment: Just for reference, what would the value for `limit` be if you were setting the column to be `LONGTEXT`?

Comment: I believe it would be `change_column :example_table, :example_text_field, :text, limit: 4.gigabytes - 1`

Answer (score 12):

```
change_column :example_table, :example_text_field, :mediumtext
```

Example:

```
def change
   change_column :users, :bio, :mediumtext
end
```

Comment: Can you provide more context?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb#L567

Comment: A little more future proof with the commit hash instead of "master": https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5220c6e/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb#L536